# Are Ubuntu DVDs available for buying in Canonical Store?

Tags: live-usb, canonical, livedvd

Times ago, Canonical announced that in the Canonical Store will be available for buying only CDs / DVDs of LTS releases: [Canonical Axes Ubuntu Discs for Non-LTS Releases](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/canonical-ditching-ubuntu-cdsdvds-for-non-lts)

But, now we have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and no DVD available in the store: [CDs or DVDs of the distributions in bulk](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)

They added only a T-Shirt. Anyone knows why, and if DVDs will be available in future for buying?

PS: I know that it's not really useful that I'm going to burn download ISO, but I like to have original Ubuntu disks.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: The official Ubuntu Shop has closed down.

Pressed DVDs of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [desktop](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146) and [server](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?currency=USD&products_id=1139) are now available to <s>pre-order</s> purchase from the Canonical store. The DVDs are only available in the 64-bit version. If you require 32-bit you will need to download a distribution or make your own DVD.

The store lists the following options (prices are current to January, 2015):

- £5.04/$8.00 for a single disk
- £8.50/$13.49 for a pack of 10
- £18.20/$28.88 for a pack of 20

The Ubuntu 14.04 disks are no longer available from the Canonical store, however an 8GB bootable USB stick of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop is available from the official [Canonical Store](https://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1206) for $7.29.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I asked directly writing to Canonical Shop support, and report here the answer.

" Ubuntu has advised that the 14.04 CDs will be available to purchase beginning of May. "